# Can I use htaccess rewrite to remove part of a URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a URL like the following:

```
www.domain.com/blog/about
```

The reason it is `/blog` first is because it is a WordPress site installed in a subfolder of my site called blog. Is it possible to remove the blog part of the URL with htaccess so that the URL would look like

```
www.domain.com/about
```

but the page being served would be the `/blog/about` page?

Comment: Sure, this is possible, but wouldn't it lead to collisions with other resources in the web root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with these rules however it will kill anything in your root directory!

```
RewriteCond $1 !^/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1
```

You may want to add a check that the requested file/directory doesn't exist first e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

That way existing files would be served everything else gets directed to the blog

Comment: What do you mean by "it will kill anything in your root directory" ?

Comment: As in any files in your web root will not be accessible via the web, hence the `RewriteCond` rules to prevent this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite that using .htaccess, but a better solution would be to point the URL to the blog folder directy. Or you can move the content out of the blog folder.